# post magento product page url on facebook

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

When I post a Magento product page URL http://www.bardolino.nl/black-cats.html on
Facebook, it displays the description with some HTML tags. How can I make this display the right description information?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Facebook's Open Graph meta tags for the shares/likes to properly display product information on Facebook.

Try this extension:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/socialshare-open-graph-3111.html

or, you can simply implement it yourself:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/304843/

Comment: i have use code but please read this url and get some help
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.bardolino.nl%2Fblack-cats.html

Comment: @ravipatel looks like your original question was answered?